# Show custom message at the bottom of a webpart in sps2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom

Environment: Sharepoint 2013 (on premise)

I want to show a custom message "more info " at the bottom of a list webpart.

Tried by adding a custom message in a Content Editor on the list page at the bottom, but doesn't shows on the WebPart.

I guess jQuery can do the job, Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is on list view you have override with context,

```
(function () {    

var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "Your message"; 
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);})();
```

Comment: Do i need it in script editor on the list page for the effectcto appear on the list webpart on home page?

Comment: If you are adding to home page
1) if you add directly to home page it applies to all list views on the page
2) you use as JS link attritube on the list view app part by adding the above script in seperate JS file

Comment: I added the script to a js file and mapped it to in the JS link section of my List Webpart.

Here is the script file, screenshot to confirm for the file format and code is correct - 
http://imgur.com/kEk9ynw

However, its not working, doesnt show any message at the bottom of the  webpart. Kindly assist.

Comment: updated JS Code file image: http://imgur.com/GZarq4J

Comment: As per article:

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/13/sharepoint-2013-js-link-tutorial/

suggests, ( JS Link Override will not work if you are using the Custom List Form (i.e. it is edited in SharePoint Designer).

Is that correct?


Also I have changed the js file with only your code and script tags 
Still the same.

Referring further to article: http://jsuhail.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/client-side-rendering-using-jslink-post_30.html

It seems it should work. In order to be clear for Javascript on my SPS 2013 is working, added to another pg still the same

Comment: However, other JS scripts are working on the same SPS page,
Please assist

Comment: Please remove script reference in the script file and also you cannot use <script src="jquer...." /> in the script file

Comment: Done still the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I`ve added the script for testing on SharePoint Online, doesnt works

Comment: please share the screenshot of ur script file its very simple one.

Comment: thanks for your assistance.

Script File Screeshot - http://imgur.com/JaIOuRd

the Js file is mapped to the SPS 2013 List view Webpart.

Additional Information - 

- SPS List is created using SPD2013 and its working fine.
- Javascript is working on the Homepage, as other Javascript features are working.

Comment: if you are mapping to List view directly with the browser , you have use tokens like "~site/{refernce to script file}", if you are using designer it is like this "~site/{refernce to script file} | clienttemplates.js", also make sure the JS link attribute to be in one line in designer, if anything is mistake it not works

Comment: Well i m mapping using the list view webpart. Do i need still wonder of token or just paste simply the link in the js section?

Comment: copy paget this one-- "~site/{link to js} | hierarchytaskslist.js"

Comment: Sorry i m confised, shall i add the link in the following format:  "/site/stylelibrary/scripts/js|footerwp.js" ?

Comment: this one-- "~site/stylelibrary/scripts/js/footerwp.js | hierarchytaskslist.js "

Comment: if the above code is not working, it should be  "~sitecollection/stylelibrary/scripts/js/footerwp.js | hierarchytaskslist.js "

Comment: Refer this link for more information : https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Couple of updates, below is been tried on the default view page of the SPS2013 List by editing the page and adding the JS link to the List webpart:

a) ~sitecollection/stylelibrary/scripts/js/footerwp.js , doesnt works

b) ~sitecollection/stylelibrary/scripts/js/footerwp.js | hierarchytaskslist.js, I`m not sure how this work as there is no file in my script folder with the name hierarchytaskslist.js

c) Removed all CSS customization on the List page, still no change.

d) Tried on SPSOnline, still the same.

Comment: Finally got the message on the list webpart. 
Only additional change, placed the Js file in "_catalogs/masterpage/footerwp.js" and it worked.

Ref Link: http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/

Comment: Can you suggest how can I set HREF to the custom footer message. I guess Jquery can do the job. 

My search so far suggests -

`code`


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#scriptPagingWPQ2').html('<a href="http://www.google.com">Footer</a>');

</script> 

`code`

But its not working, moreover this would add a new text and wont provide HREF on the Footer message placed via the JS file. Any further suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution, on how to add text with hyperlink using Jscript. 

Thanks to Shiva for the support on the JS file code to add Footer message.